# Add Data Attributes to Custom Wrapper using Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have created a custom wrapper for simple_form but I can't seem to find a way to add data attributes to the generated wrapper element. I'm trying to add it to the inner wrapper class called switch.

I want to be able to add it to the wrapper, not in view layer if possible.

```
config.wrappers :toggle, :tag => 'div', :class => 'control-group', :error_class => 'error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.use :placeholder
  b.use :label
  b.wrapper :tag => 'div', :class => 'controls' do |ba|
    ba.wrapper :tag => 'div', :class => 'switch' do |box|
      box.use :input
    end
    ba.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => 'span', :class => 'help-block' }
    ba.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => 'span', :class => 'help-inline' }
  end
end

= form.input :element, :label => t('views.items.attributes.element'), :wrapper => :toggle
```

**Output**

```
<div class="control-group boolean optional">
  <label class="boolean optional control-label" for="item_element">Element</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="switch">
      <input name="item[element]" type="hidden" value="0">
      <input class="boolean optional" id="item_element" name="item[element]" type="checkbox" value="1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<div class="control-group boolean optional">
  <label class="boolean optional control-label" for="item_element">Element</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="switch" data-label="blah" data-id="something">
      <input name="item[element]" type="hidden" value="0">
      <input class="boolean optional" id="item_element" name="item[element]" type="checkbox" value="1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

[@Learner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14874037/171183) is close. The trick is to include an `html` hash:

```rb
ba.wrapper tag: 'div', 
           html: { data: { id: 'something', label: 'blah' }, 
           class: 'switch' do |box|
  box.use :input
end
```

Note: This approach works on the `<builder>.wrapper` methods, but not on `config.wrappers`, `<builder>.use`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `:data => {:id=> 'something', :label => 'blah'}` after the tag name in your wrapper

```
config.wrappers :toggle, :tag => 'div', :class => 'control-group', :error_class => 'error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.use :placeholder
  b.use :label
  b.wrapper :tag => 'div', :class => 'controls' do |ba|
    ba.wrapper :tag => 'div', :data => {:id=> 'something', :label => 'blah'}, :class => 'switch' do |box|
      box.use :input
    end
    ba.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => 'span', :class => 'help-block' }
    ba.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => 'span', :class => 'help-inline' }
  end
end

= form.input :element, :label => t('views.items.attributes.element'), :wrapper => :toggle
```

Even you could add name, and some values like the following:

```
:data => {:name => 'Stephen', :city_state => %w(Chicago IL)}
```

Comment: I had tried this before, well technically I tried:

ba.wrapper :tag => 'div', :class => 'switch', :data => { :id => 'as', :label => 'label' } do |box|
end

I tried your way as well now to verify it wasn't an order of args but it still didn't work. I wonder if it has to do with simple_form_bootstrap overriding it somehow?